# mb_substr() undefined Facebook canvas - Heroku server

Tags: php, heroku, mbstring

The problem is that when I open the facebook canvas. I get this error. "call to undefined function mb_substr"

[image]

The solution that most people suggest is to put "ext-mbstring" as a require. I did that in different way's. This is what I have now:

```
{
  "require" : {
    "silex/silex": "~1.3",
    "monolog/monolog": "~1.7",
    "twig/twig": "^1.19",
    "symfony/twig-bridge": "^2.7"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "heroku/heroku-buildpack-php": "*"
  },
    "require": {
    "ext-mbstring": "*"
}
}
```

This does not work for me. I have also checked the php info of my heroku server.
This is the output. As you can see the mbstring is set. 
[image]

What I at last think the problem could be is the php version. Facebook wants a version that's higher than 5.4. I am using version 5.6.15.
So that shouldn't be the problem either.

Anyone knows what I missed?

Comment: "--enable_...=shared" means that the extension module was compiled as a shared object/dll when the php core was build. It tells you nothing about whether the module is actually available or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a JSON object and `require` is the property key, I don't think you can just add a second property with the same key. Try to add the dependency to the first `require` property.

```
{
  "require" : {
    "php": ">=5.6.0",
    "ext-mbstring": "*",
    "silex/silex": "~1.3",
    "monolog/monolog": "~1.7",
    "twig/twig": "^1.19",
    "symfony/twig-bridge": "^2.7"
  },
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already tried that. It gave me the same result. So that's why I tried it separately. 
I'm quite stuck on this one. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to run composer update after you make changes to composer.json.